# iOS: popover on iPhone app

Tags: ios, popover

In my app for IPHONE I use a popover but I don't know if my app will be reject if I use this element in iPhone app and not in iPad app; do you know if I can have this problem?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no problem and there are many apps having that feature but you need to code it yourself that popover function is not available for iPhone. A app I often use that has that feature is called Week Cal.

Answer (score 0):

Apple can reject for anything. However that being said I have seen numerous applications for iPhone that use custom popovers. Facebook app is just one example. You should be fine as long as you don't use any private API's